# Second gen ipod shuffle not working with rhythmbox

Tags: 10.10, rhythmbox, ipod

I'm trying to get a second gen ipod shuffle to work with Ubuntu 10.10. As far as i understand Rhythymbox should support this. When I plug the ipod in it shows up under the devices section of the menu, but after that I am unable to do anything with it.

I can't see the songs that are already on it, I can't add new songs, I can't do anything. When i attempt to drag a song across, absolutely nothing happens. if i try the sync with library option, it shuts rhythymbox down completely. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't get rhythmbox or banshee to work with my 2nd gen Shuffle but gtkpod works perfectly without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I got into many troubles when I tried to force rhythmbox to work with iPods (many different generations). Eventually, I got into conclusion that rhythmbox is simply unable to work with them properly. I tried out some ipod-dedicated software, but most turned out to be an useless junk... but there is one, I can recommend you: it's Floola http://www.floola.com/ 
It gives you a simple but powerful access to your iPod, I appreciate the fact it was the only application that managed to communicate properly with my iPod without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it should not be needed.

http://shuffle-db.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Im having problems similar to this.  Seems rhythmbox, and possible Ubuntu itself is buggy with ipods.   Here's a link to the forum with others having a similar problem with other ipods.     http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9978297#post9978297

Comment: This entry seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find its actually the libraries they all use that are broken (and its fairly well documented) which is why no applications using the libgpod do not work. Been like that for a year now, im still stuck on old music :/